# How to get distance between current location and the next current location

Tags: java, android, gps, geolocation, android-location

I am having trouble figuring how to get the distance between 2 non fixed locations. The first location is my current location and the second is the latest current location after walking say 100 meters. Below is a snippet of code.

```
/**
 * Callback that fires when the location changes.
 */
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    mCurrentLocation = location;
    updateUI();
}


/**
 * Updates the latitude, the longitude, and the last location time in the UI.
 */
private void updateUI() {

    latitude = mCurrentLocation.getLatitude();
    longitude = mCurrentLocation.getLongitude();

    mLatitudeTextView.setText(String.format("%s: %f", mLatitudeLabel,latitude));
    mLongitudeTextView.setText(String.format("%s: %f", mLongitudeLabel, longitude));
}
```

So below I have my mCurrentLocation but how do I get the newCurrentLocation so I use the distanceTo method.

```
double distance = mCurrentLocation.distanceTo(newCurrentLocation);
```

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: save old location before overwrite mCurrentLocation.

Comment: Do you mean saving the old location to a database? If so I want to avoid this if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to save the current location in a temporary variable, something like this:

```
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    Location temp = mCurrentLocation;     //save the old location      
    mCurrentLocation = location;          //get the new location
    distance = mCurrentLocation.distanceTo(temp);   //find the distance     
    updateUI();
}
```